# Method 'Paste' of object '_Worksheet' failed when pasting graph

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to copy a graph from a worksheet("Copy Graph") and then paste it to another worksheet("Paste Graph") as a picture. Here is what I have:

```
Dim ws as worksheet
Set ws = Worksheets("Paste Graph") 

Worksheets("Copy Graph").ChartObjects("Chart 1").Activate
ActiveChart.Parent.CopyPicture
ws.Paste Destination:=ws.Range("E16")
```

It works on my computer but when I ran it on another computer, I got the error: " Method 'Paste' of object '_Worksheet' failed"

I guess it is because of the use of "activate". Should I activate the destination range before pasting?

Also is there a way to improve the codes? I feel it's quite easy to crash.

Thank you!!!

Comment: What worksheet is ws?

Comment: @GMalc ws it's another worksheet but it's on the same workbook with "Copy Graph"

Comment: Well in the context of your question, `ws.Paste` looks like it would throw run-time error 91 for not being `Set` to anything. Please read [mcve].

Comment: @MathieuGuindon I edited the question. Thank you for your comment.

Comment: Actually I tested your code and it perfectly worked without throwing any error. I cannot reproduce it. Actually you don't need to `.Activate` the chart instead you can dircetly copy it using `ChartObjects("Chart 1").CopyPicture`. Make sure the worksheet `Worksheets("Copy Graph")` is the active sheet when copying the chart.